# Facebook Page Plugin not scrolling in Safari?

Tags: ios, facebook, safari

Just created a new Facebook feed for a site using their ‘Page Plugin’ tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

For some reason once the code is generated and on the website for example:

http://www.st-columbas-earlyyears.org/facebook_feed.html

When viewing the page on Safari (7.1.5) on the mac (Mavericks) and iOS Safari (8.2) users are unable the scroll the feed.

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe name="f3d8169228" width="300px" height="423px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:page Facebook Social Plugin" src="http://www.facebook.com/v2.3/plugins/page.php?app_id=&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FKvoNGODIqPG.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df2009d0444%26domain%3Dwww.st-columbas-earlyyears.org%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.st-columbas-earlyyears.org%252Ffdf710f6%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=1202&amp;height=423&amp;hide_cover=true&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fstcolumbasfpfriends&amp;locale=en_GB&amp;sdk=joey&amp;show_facepile=false&amp;show_posts=true&amp;width=300" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 300px; height: 423px;" class=""></iframe>
```

I'm on chrome, doesn't scroll either because "scrolling" is set to "no". Set it to "true" and i was able to scroll!

Comment: Thanks, have deleted Facebook's embed code as this is automatically generating the iframe code so have no control over the scrolling attribute and have now replaced it with an actual iframe using the link.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying the new "FB page plugin".
Scrolling works intermittently.
Usually works on iMac (Mavericks) but very random on iPad and iPhone 6 (ios 8.2 )
Today it is not scrolling on any of them.
Hopefully FB will fix this.

Comment: Cheers Pete, thanks for confirming it's not just me.